# How to embed google search results in a jquery mobile webpage?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, embed

I need to take an input term and embed google search results in a jquery mobile app. How can I do this ?

Comment: @Daan - I understand. It's an app. This page is just one part of it. I have most of the other stuff done. I know about embedding frames, but that seems too primitive. Other than that I have no clue how one would go about doing this. I am not expecting the answer to be a code, but a hint or pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this would work for your situation but you could check out https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Just kinda sucks that they charge after a certain number of queries.